# I am trying to log into capcut via the website using selenium but I cannot click on one button

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on this button

```
<button class="lv-btn lv-btn-primary lv-btn-size-default lv-btn-shape-square lv_sign_in_panel_wide-primary-button" type="button"><span>Continue</span></button>
```

Using this code

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value="lv-btn lv-btn-primary lv-btn-size-default lv-btn-shape-square lv_sign_in_panel_wide-primary-button").click()
```

But i get the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".lv-btn lv-btn-primary lv-btn-size-default lv-btn-shape-square lv_sign_in_panel_wide-primary-button"}
```

I know this is due to another element before my button having a higher z-index

```
<div class="lv-modal-wrapper lv-modal-wrapper-align-center" style="z-index: 1102; display: block;">
```

I know i can click on the previous buttons but I cannot access this button to move to the next step.
FYI: I am using chrome driver 117, on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not due to another element before my button having a higher z-index.

You are using `By.CLASS_NAME` for finding the element, selenium convert this to a `CSS_SELECTOR` based from this code snippet `def find_element`

```py
if by == By.ID:
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    value = f'[id="{value}"]'
elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    value = f".{value}"
elif by == By.NAME:
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    value = f'[name="{value}"]'
```

Your code

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value="lv-btn lv-btn-primary lv-btn-size-default lv-btn-shape-square lv_sign_in_panel_wide-primary-button").click()
```

Is equivalent to

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".lv-btn lv-btn-primary lv-btn-size-default lv-btn-shape-square lv_sign_in_panel_wide-primary-button").click()
```

Which of course will not work since `.lv-btn lv-btn-primary lv-btn-size-default lv-btn-shape-square lv_sign_in_panel_wide-primary-button` can't be found in the DOM.

The fix is to use a proper selector

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value="lv_sign_in_panel_wide-primary-button").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".lv_sign_in_panel_wide-primary-button").click()
```